# Write quadratic fractional program in CVXPY

Tags: cvxpy

I am trying the write the following quasiconvex function in CVXPY, which I eventually want to minimize.

```
# Import packages
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# parameters
A1 = np.matrix([[2,1],[1,3]])
A2 = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,4]])

# create model
x = cp.Variable(2)
f = cp.quad_form(x,A1,assume_PSD=True)
h = -cp.quad_form(x,A2,assume_PSD=True) + 10
quadFrac = f / h

# check the function type
print("f is convex: ",f.is_convex())
print("h is concave: ",h.is_concave())
print("f/h is quasiconvex: ",quadFrac.is_quasiconvex())
print("f/h is ",quadFrac.curvature)
```

I know that this function `f/h` is quasiconvex for all `x` where `h(x)>0` based on [Boyd's textbook exercise 4.7](https://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf). However, when I check the function curvature it says it is unknown. I think this is due to not following explicit [DQCP composition rules](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dqcp/index.html#composition-rules).

**So, how can I write this function in CVXPY for it to be recognized as quasiconvex?**

Based on the [DQCP atoms](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dqcp/index.html#dqcp-atoms), the *Ratio* atom seems to be able to accommodate my function where it says

> ...the ratio of a nonnegative convex function and a positive concave function is quasiconvex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note that this is OUTSIDE the standard use of CVXPY. So be careful about any decisions based on the results**

I discussed this with some people on Discord. Taking into account DQCP, wraps, signs, and curvature, this an appropriate (hacky) way to solve the problem

```
# import
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# parameters
A1 = np.matrix([[2,1],[1,3]])
A2 = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,4]])

# create variables and functions
x = cp.Variable(2)
f = cp.quad_form(x,A1,assume_PSD=True)
h = -cp.quad_form(x,A2,assume_PSD=True) + 10

# assertions
h = cp.atoms.affine.wraps.nonneg_wrap(h)

# function
F = f/h

# check assertions
print("f is ",f.sign,f.curvature)
print("h is ",h.sign,h.curvature)
print("t is ",t.sign,t.curvature)
print("F is ",F.sign,F.curvature)

# constraints
constraints = [h >= 1e-4]

# problem
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(F),constraints)

# solve
assert problem.is_dqcp()
problem.solve(qcp=True)

# print results
print(x.value)
```